# Inverting if condition with boolean

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

More of a curiosity than anything. I currently have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
var inputsArray=[];
userInputs.forEach(input=>{
        if(isInvert ? query.name == input.name : query.name != input.name){
              inputsArray.push(input.id);
        }
    });
```

Before that i had:

```
            var inputsArray=[];
            userInputs.forEach(input=>{
               if(isInvert){
                    if (query.name == input.name){
                       inputsArray.push(input.id);
                    }
              }else {
                   if (query.name != input.name){
                      inputsArray.push(input.id);
                    }
              }
          });
```

Essentially when `isInvert` is `true` the opposite values are going to be stored to when `isInverse` is `false`. I'm wondering if there is an even better way to write the first snippet of code?

Comment: Your second snippet is much more readable than the first (except that you should use `filter` here, not `forEach`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can further simplify to

```
if (isInvert == (query.name == input.name)) {
    inputsArray.push(input.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this `if(isInvert ^ (query.name != input.name)) inputsArray.push(input.id);` wher ^ is the XOR operation